# How to get the name of a dictionary in embedded dict in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, error-handling, flask

I want to make a list of errors which I can return in my API which I'm building with Flask. Since I didn't know how to do this internally, I thought of the following:

```
ERRORS = {
    'something_went_wrong': {
        'code': 1, 
        'type': 'something_went_wrong', 
        'message': 'Something went horribly wrong. Check yo self.'
    },
    'something_else_went_wrong': {
        'code': 2, 
        'type': 'something_else_went_wrong', 
        'message': 'Now something else went wrong..'
    },
}
```

If I then want to create an error response, I simple get the error from the dict, and pass it to a function which returns the error. This works ok so far. The only thing I don't like, is that I list the `type` double. First as key for the dictionary, and later as a `'type'` within the dictionary. Is there a way to reference the type as the key with which it is known in the encapsulating dictionary?

All tips are welcome; also about how I can improve my error reporting setup.. :)

Comment: Why not just pass the key to the function, and the key doubles up as the type value?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I really like the simple solution of this. Thanks for that. Do you know if this is a common way to structure errors at all? Or is there no common way?

Comment: I generally use exceptions; the exception class then embodies the various properties, and code just raises that exception.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Do you maybe have a link to an open source project on Github which shows this type of use?

Comment: Not of the top of my head, sorry.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Doesn't matter. Thanks a million anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep your structure as it is, try to use a helper function, i.e.

```
def printError(err_type):
    if ERRORS.has_key(err_type):
        print "Type:", err_type
        print "Message:", ERRORS[err_type].get("message")
        print "Code:", ERRORS[err_type].get("code")
```

Thus calling `printError("something_went_wrong")` you will reference to type, that is defined as a key in your dictionary.

Comment: You should use `in` instead of `has_key`.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to pre-generate your error messages like this, but don't want to repeat yourself with with these literals, you might try creating a class object which stores the error as a field, build a bunch of objects and add them to the dictionary:

```
class MyAPIError(object):
    error_map = {}
    def __init__(self, code, error_type, message):
          self.code = code
          self.error_type = error_type
          self.message = message
          self.error_map[error_type] = self


err1 = MyAPIError(1, "something_went_wrong", 'Something went horribly wrong. Check yo self.')
err2 = MyAPIError(2, "something_else_went_wrong", 'Now something else went wrong..')

MyAPIError.error_map
...
```

This way, whenever you create a new error, it automatically registers itself with the class-wide map, and you don't need to explicitly add it, or repeat literals.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I don't really see the added advantage of this. I really like Martijn Pieters suggestion which he made in his comment below the initial question. How would your answer benefit me from his comment?